# Image stretches unexpectedly in td

Tags: html, html-table

I'm just a beginner but I have been working with this problem for hours now.

Applying the image in the td will strech the whole table into a weird size and ruin everything. The table is 500 x 500 and 5 columns and rows, 2 columns are needed for that gif. The gif's size is 200 x 200. But why does it stretch that way ?

Before applying gif:

[image: link]

The code before gif is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#264663">
        <table style="width:500px;height:500px;table-layout:fixed;" bgcolor="#fddab4" align="center" border="10" bordercolor="#d12a5b" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4" colspan="2"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

And after:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#264663">
    <table style="width:500px;height:500px;table-layout:fixed;" bgcolor="#fddab4" align="center" border="10" bordercolor="#d12a5b" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" colspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><img style="display:block;" width="100%" src="/pics/meanwhileatnintendo.gif" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: I tried removing height="100%" but then this happens:

[image: LINK HERE]

Comment: Calm down ;) Seriously though, I'm gonna edit the all caps, take a moment and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The 100% height is causing the problem.

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><img style="display:block;" width="100%"  src="/pics/meanwhileatnintendo.gif" /></td>
```

As long as your image is square this should work.

Comment: Still aligns improperly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, after hours of trial and error,this works:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OB2F.jpg)

`

```
<head>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#264663">
    <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:500px;height:500px;border-collapse:collapse;" bgcolor="#fddab4" border="10" bordercolor="#d12a5b" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" background="/pics/5to1.jpg" height="100" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" colspan="2" height="400" width="200"></td>
            <td height="100" width="100"></td>
            <td height="100" width="100"></td>
            <td height="100" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="100" width="100"></td>
            <td height="100" width="100"></td>
            <td height="100" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="100" width="100"></td>
            <td height="200" colspan="2" rowspan="2" width="200" style="background-image:url(/pics/meanwhileatnintendo.gif)">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="100" width="100"></td>
        </table>
</body>
```

`

But, I want to know that is there a more effective and shorter way to make the cells keep their sizes even when content is being added!

That was my problem: The cells kept changing size even from adding a single letter in them. Now that I have stated the size of each cell individually, the cells won't resize anymore and that's great! But still, alot of typing needed for such a simple problem. Any other way?